# Can node.js be used to get a webpage given the URL?

Tags: node.js

Can node.js be used to get a webpage given the URL? This may mean node.js should be able to run other javaScript code applicable for that web page.

Comment: look at phantomjs, it executes the js of the page in another context. or try casperjs which is easier and based on phantomjs

Comment: you should not do this -> why would you want to execute external javascript?


node.js only has one progress and if you do that it can break + the other side can actually inject whatever they want

Comment: Yes it can. What are you doing exactly that you are asking it? Can you detail what you are doing

Comment: @wodka: "why would you want to execute external javascript?" => to do scraping

Comment: @Gary The proposal is to use node.js for the server-side of a web application. Now, the server-side functions in the app include getting the web page given a URL (the URL is provided interactively by the app-user or picked from a dynamic list that grows over time). It is similar to web-scraping though not exactly it. If it is possible, I suppose it could be thorough a handle, provided by node.js, to the JavaScript Engine under which node.js  itself is executing or through a System.execute() call passing the JavaScript-engine command. Can you pl confirm and describe the specifics?

Comment: It should be possible but I have not heard of a tool do it. Have you tried curl or similar tool in npm. Its highly insecure and not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

For Scraping or printing an existing webpage try http://phantomjs.org/

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
  //Page is loaded!
  phantom.exit();
});
```